# How to display notification popup with animation appearing and decreasing from right top to bottom and closing from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently, my notification popup work but I would like to do this animation without JS/JQuery **(only animation)**. Also there is an issue with clicking. When you click outside when popup is open, then work normally. But if you click on this text *OPEN*, then ending animation won't work.
Animation appearing and decreasing from right top to bottom and closing from bottom to top. It should work in both directions but alternately. It currently only works when you want close popup.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/konradstrek/0bgtnLho/)

CSS

```
.e-p-main {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  -ms-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: transform .15s ease-out, -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
}

.tsc_1 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#e_a_c").click(function(e) {
    $("#t_1").toggle();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#t_1").addClass("tsc_1");
    }, 1);
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('#t_1 *')) {
      $("#t_1").removeClass("tsc_1");
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#t_1').removeAttr('style');
      }, 150)
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<a class="open-edit-popup" id="e_a_c">OPEN</a>

<div id="e_a_p">
  <div class="e-p-cont">
    <div class="e-p-main" id="t_1">
      <div class="e-p-text-1 dps">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably NOT the answer; more a starter.
I don't think you will reach your expectations with a full CSS solution, just because closing your menu by clicking outside of it can't be done without javascript.

Anyway, this is a working version with javascript / jquery
https://jsfiddle.net/piiantom/98sfoLcg/
I reworked the javascript part in order to have a functional event management.
The bugs you are refering to are fixed.

**HTML**

```
<a class="open-edit-popup" id="e_a_c">OPEN</a>

<div id="e_a_p">
  <div class="e-p-cont">
    <div class="e-p-main" id="t_1">
      <div class="e-p-text-1 dps">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#e_a_c").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#t_1").hasClass("tsc_1")) {
            $("#t_1").removeClass("tsc_1");
    } else {
            $("#t_1").addClass("tsc_1");
    }
  });
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if ($("#t_1").hasClass("tsc_1")) {
      $("#t_1").removeClass("tsc_1");
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.e-p-main {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  -ms-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: transform .15s ease-out, -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
}

.tsc_1 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

For the full CSS version, this is a working version by using the checkbox input hack. But, the opening / closing is only managed by clicking on OPEN. Menu is not closed when clicking outside.
https://jsfiddle.net/piiantom/oht40Lk5/
Besides, all your menu is nested inside a `<label>`, which is not that good

**HTML**

```
<label>OPEN<input type="checkbox" class="open-edit-popup" id="e_a_c"/>
  <div id="e_a_p">
  <div class="e-p-cont">
    <div class="e-p-main" id="t_1">
      <div class="e-p-text-1 dps">
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
        <p>test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</label>
```

**CSS**

```
#e_a_c{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#e_a_c:checked+#e_a_p #t_1{
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


.e-p-main {
  margin-top: 40px;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 99;
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
  -ms-transform-origin: top right;
  transform-origin: top right;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
  -o-transition: transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: transform .15s ease-out;
  transition: transform .15s ease-out, -webkit-transform .15s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Both solutions made it easier for me to do what I expected. Thank you for your answer.